# Changing contrast and brightness with Magick.NET or GraphicsMagick.NET. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

How can I change contrast and brightness using GraphicsMagick.NET?

The apparent method for contrast only receives a boolean, so I don't know how I can apply a range of contrast variations. For changing the brightness there isn't any method that seems to do that. Or do I need to apply several "filters" to be able to change any of these characteristics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both libraries have support for the BrightnessContrast method that uses a percentage to specify the range:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("logo:"))
{
  image.BrightnessContrast(10, 10);
  image.Write(@"C:\test.png");
}
```

Comment: I simply don't know how to react to this.... I had cycled trough all the methods at least 5 times to see if I could find any that would do the trick and didn't see that one :S